# Displaying the same order of keys which I have in my list of dictionary keys in my output

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, openerp-7, odoo-8

I am using python 2.7.X version and I need to display my result of list of dictionary in key order same as in my output.

**CREATE THE LIST OF DICTIONARY :**

```
for acc_data in acc_pool.browse(cr,uid,acc_ids_in):
    for line in acc_data.invoice_line:
        c+=1
        lst_data2.append({
            'SupplierName':acc_data.partner_id.name or '',
            'SupplierBRN':acc_data.partner_id.com_reg_no1 or '',
            'InvoiceDate':acc_data.date_invoice or '',
            'InvoiceNumber':acc_data.number or '',
            'ImportDeclarationNo':'',
            'LineNumber':c,
            'ProductDescription':line.product_id.name or '',
            'PurchaseValueMYR':line.price_unit or 0.00,
            'GSTValueMYR':'',
            'TaxCode':line.invoice_line_tax_id.name or '',
            'FCYCode':'',
            'PurchaseFCY':'',
            'GSTFCY':'',
            })
```

**RESULT :**

```
> lst_data2 [{'ProductDescription': u'Ink Cartridge', 'SupplierBRN': '', 'ImportDeclarationNo': '', 'GSTValueMYR': '', 'SupplierName': u'Vicking Direct', 'GSTFCY': '', 'TaxCode': u'Purchase Tax 15.00%', 'InvoiceDate': '2015-03-24', 'FCYCode': '', 'PurchaseFCY': '', 'PurchaseValueMYR': 58.0, 'LineNumber': 1, 'InvoiceNumber': u'EXJ/2015/002'}, {'ProductDescription': u'Toner Cartridge', 'SupplierBRN': '', 'ImportDeclarationNo': '', 'GSTValueMYR': '', 'SupplierName': u'Vicking Direct', 'GSTFCY': '', 'TaxCode': u'OTAX X', 'InvoiceDate': '2015-03-24', 'FCYCode': '', 'PurchaseFCY': '', 'PurchaseValueMYR': 65.0, 'LineNumber': 2, 'InvoiceNumber': u'EXJ/2015/002'}]
```

Here you can easily see my order of keys is different than the order of keys in my result.

My question is that I need to displaying the same order of keys which I have in my list of dictionary keys in my output.

How can I set the same order of list of keys to be in my result ?

Comment: You might think that shouting in your title makes your question more noticeable. You're right, it does. Not in a nice way, though, and people will be less likely to want to answer your question. Please edit your title. Also, your code is not a syntactically correct Python; please fix your indentation.

Comment: okey i will check that one again and improve my formating

Comment: You can't: a dict is by definition unordered. You could perhaps use [named tuples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dict` does not remember order. [`ordereddict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) does; use that.

Unfortunately, you can't use the `dict` literal, because as soon as you do, you lose ordering. You can use this syntax:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
o = OrderedDict([("a", 1), ("b", 2)])
# `a` is first; `b` is second.
```

Comment: my result give me that one list have multiple dictionary but when I print that one that it gives me the ValueError: too many values to unpack Error            I have tryed from my side some think like this                       o = OrderedDict(lst_data2)

Comment: You can't convert `lst_data2` into OrderedDict, since a) it is in the wrong format, and even if you could, b) it already contains an unordered dict, so your values will be scrambled already. Try `lst_data2.append(OrderedDict([('SupplierName', acc_data.partner_id.name or ''), ('SupplierBRN', acc_data.partner_id.com_reg_no1 or ''), ... ]))`

Comment: hello Amadan its gives me the same error again ..                           ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: When you do what exactly?

Comment: do the same what exactly you asked to me

Comment: I can't enter `same what exactly you asked to me` into my interpreter to test it. I already tested *my* code before I gave it to you, so I know it works. If you just wanted to inform me that you couldn't apply my solution, that's fine. If you wanted me to help you debug it, you need to show me the code *you* wrote. If it's more than one line, it's probably best to edit it into the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73907/discussion-between-dasadiya-chaitanya-and-amadan).

Answer (score 0):

I have Resolved my posted Question.

Just We need to add the python Library our  File and use it as follow.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

    for acc_data in acc_pool.browse(cr,uid,acc_ids_in):
        c=0
        for line in acc_data.invoice_line:
            if line.invoice_line_tax_id:
                c+=1
                lst_data2.append(OrderedDict([
                    ('SupplierName',acc_data.partner_id.name or ''),
                    ('SupplierBRN',acc_data.partner_id.com_reg_no or ''),
                    ('InoiveDate',acc_data.date_invoice or ''),
                    ('InvoiceNumber',acc_data.number or ''),
                    ('ImportDeclarationNo',''),
                    ('LineNumber',c),
                    ('ProductDescription',line.product_id.name or ''),
                    ('PurchaseValueMYR',line.price_unit or 0.00),
                    ('GSTValueMYR',''),
                    ('TaxCode',line.invoice_line_tax_id.name or ''),
                    ('FCYCode',''),
                    ('PurchaseFCY',''),
                    ('GSTFCY',''),
                    ]))
```

I hope this should helpful for some one. :)